# Correct pronunciation of possessives ending on "-s"

Tags: pronunciation, possessives

What's the correct pronunciation of possessives ending on "-s"?
For example,

> Mrs Harri**s's** house.
>
> Mr Rice**s's** dog.
>
> Noris**s's** estate.

Comment: @ColleenV: the question you linked is about spelling. This question and the one I linked are about pronunciation of the possessives.

Comment: @Void Then we should vote to reopen the one you linked because it was closed as a duplicate of the one I chose. I was in a hurry and didn’t look closely. I just don’t like closing a question as a duplicate of a question closed as a duplicate of something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like an additional syllable pronounced "iz," unstressed.

Harris's → /**har'** is iz/
Rices's → /**rIs'** iz iz/
Noriss's → /**nor'** is iz/